# change primary color with hex color in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to change the primary color in my app so I tried:

```
theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: const Color(0xFF784CEF),
),
```

but that didn't work so I checked the documentation
I found another way of doing it which is using

```dart
colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
    primarySwatch: Colors.red,
    // but I want 0xFF784CEF as my primary color so I tried
    // primarySwatch: Color(0xFF784CEF), 
    // which gives me an error saying `The argument type 'Color' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MaterialColor'.`
),
```

So my question is: how to change the primary color with a hexadecimal color

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On `MaterialApp` `theme`

```dart
theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
  colorScheme: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(
        primary: const Color(0xFF784CEF),
      ),
),
```

Comment: worked thanks for your help. but you said 'On `MaterialApp` `theme`', I've been looking for that page but found nth. can you please provide the link you took the code from?

Comment: I follow the concept of [extending-the-parent-theme](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes#extending-the-parent-theme) and while we are suggested to use `colorScheme` I follow this approach.